# Cascade remove not working.cascade={"remove"}

Tags: doctrine-orm, cascade

I am using Doctrine 2. I have an entity wherein I have self join. Two columns in join are :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entities\wall_post", inversedBy="shared_wallpost")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="wall_post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $shared_from_wallpost;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entities\wall_post", mappedBy="shared_from_wallpost", cascade={"remove"})
 */
private $shared_wallpost;
```

> Lets say there are two posts: one id = 1001 second id = 1002 ( having
>   wall_post_id = 1001)
>
> now I want when I delete 1001 , post with wall_post_id 1001 gets
>   deleted.

For this I am using cascade={"remove"} but it does not work.
My query to delete wallpost object:

```
//Removing record from table.

    $qb_1 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
                $qb_1->delete('\Entities\wall_post', 'wp');
                $qb_1->where( 'wp.id  = ?1' );
                $qb_1->setParameter('1', $wallpost_id );
                $qb_1->getQuery()->execute();
                $em -> flush();
```

Comment: The mapping looks ok. Are you flushing the entity manager after removing?

Comment: @manix I have added added my query to delete object in my answer please have look. I am using $em->flush; but no use. Thanks.

Comment: i'm not sure why your current code doesn't work but you can try `onDelete="CASCADE"` as an alternative

Comment: @FuzzyTree Tried that one also. But no success. Thanks for your input guys!

Comment: Change  `$qb_1->setParameter('1', $wallpost_id );` to  $qb_1->setParameter(1, $wallpost_id );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cascade={“remove”} 
We have to use:

```
$em->remove($wallpost_obj);
            $em->flush();
```

I had used :

```
 $qb_1 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
                $qb_1->delete('\Entities\wall_post', 'wp');
                $qb_1->where( 'wp.id  = ?1' );
                $qb_1->setParameter('1', $wallpost_id );
                $qb_1->getQuery()->execute();
                $em -> flush();
```

Now cascade remove is working.